# How should I store a small amount of event data and share it between two asp.net pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a PHP developer and have been asked to make some amends to an Asp.Net site. There is a hardcoded table on one page which contains event information (Date, venue etc). The page uses javascript to toggle table row colours based on whether the event has already happened.

I need to add a block on another page which displays 2 upcoming events based on the current date. What is the simplest way to store and share the event data between pages? There is no database available so it needs to be a local file or array etc.

I would appreciate some insight on any good libraries / techniques which would be appropriate. This is for a simple, low-traffic site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a small class that represents your `Event`, then you can store it in the [`Session` state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx):

```
public class EventInfo
{
    //c# auto-implemented properties
    public string Bla {get; set;} 
    public int Bla2 {get; set;}
}

//set on one page
var eventInfo = new EventInfo();
eventInfo.Bla = "bla";
eventInfo.Bla1 = 2;
Sesssion["eventinfo"] = eventInfoObject;


//get on another
var eventInfo = (EventInfo)Session["eventinfo"]; //add null checks etc
string bla = eventInfo.Bla;
int Bla2 = eventInfo.Bla2;

//************************************************//

//set multiple events in Session  
List<EventInfo> events = new List<EventInfo>();   
events.Add(new EventInfo{ Bla= "bla", Bla1 = 2});
events.Add(new EventInfo{ Bla= "bla2", Bla1 = 3});
Sesssion["eventCollection"] = events ;

//get 
List<EventInfo> events = (List<EventInfo>)Session["eventCollection"]; //add null checks etc
foreach(EventInfo event in Events)
{
    string bla = event.Bla;
    int Bla2 = event.Bla2;
}
```

Comment: You should make sure that the Session is available on your project. If the site is load-balanced then it may not be the best way to do it - in this case you may have to look at a cookie based solution.

Comment: Agree, this is a loaded question, there are a bunch of solutions.

Comment: I don't think cookies would be a good idea as the user's browser could be blocking them. The Session will be available.

Comment: is {get; set;} shorthand /pseudocode or will that autogenerate getters and setters? Also, how would I add multiple events to the Session['eventInfo'] array? Am I going to hit a problem with the array being immutable?

Comment: and how do I retrieve the eventInfo.Bla1 property from the session?

Comment: See updates, added comments and another example for collections.

Answer (score 1):

you can use session for it.

```
 Session["data"] = value;
```

you can store any object in session and cast it while retrieving it, like

```
Session["data"] = 1;
```

and

```
int value =  Session["data"] != null ? (int)Session["data"] : 0
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Session variables.